# Email error "Authentication is required for relay"

Tags: email, smtp

I have recently moved all of my websites to a new (and more secure server). Out of 50 customers, 2-3 are having email issues, specifically with sending emails within the same domain and to domains on the same server.

*Here's a sample error message:*

> Diagnostic information for administrators:
>
> Generating server: AMXPR04MB247.eurprd04.prod.outlook.com
>
> pat@moonspace.co.uk babcom-h2.lnc.net Remote Server returned '550
>   Authentication is required for relay'
>
> Original message headers:
>
> Received: from DB3PRD0411HT001.eurprd04.prod.outlook.com
>   (10.255.73.36) by  AMXPR04MB247.eurprd04.prod.outlook.com
>   (10.242.72.18) with Microsoft SMTP  Server (TLS) id 15.0.800.7; Fri,
>   15 Nov 2013 08:54:25 +0000 Received: from [192.168.1.10]
>   (109.145.84.154) by pod51014.outlook.com  (10.255.73.36) with
>   Microsoft SMTP Server (TLS) id 14.16.371.2; Fri, 15 Nov  2013 08:54:24
>   +0000 From: Franklyn Nevard  Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
>     boundary="Apple-Mail=_2340A5CF-1977-490C-A345-7D19967ACFFE"
>   Message-ID:
>   
>   MIME-Version: 1.0 (Mac OS X Mail 7.0 (1822)) Subject: Re: Hosting
>   invoice from MoonSpace Date: Fri, 15 Nov 2013 08:54:21 +0000
>   References: <52851A01.7090302@moonspace.co.uk> To: Pat Dobson
>    In-Reply-To: <52851A01.7090302@moonspace.co.uk>
>   X-Mailer: Apple Mail (2.1822) Return-Path:
>   franklyn@franklynnevard.co.uk X-Originating-IP: [109.145.84.154]
>   X-Forefront-PRVS: 0031A0FFAF X-Forefront-Antispam-Report: 
>   SFV:NSPM;SFS:(71364002)(51704005)(199002)(189002)(24454002)(81342001)(74366001)(56816003)(16601075003)(76786001)(16236675002)(65816001)(63696002)(15202345003)(53806001)(82746002)(69556001)(15974865002)(81542001)(4396001)(80022001)(76796001)(51856001)(77156001)(15975445006)(87266001)(87286001)(66066001)(46102001)(85306002)(36756003)(74706001)(83716003)(83322001)(83072001)(71186001)(57306001)(33656001)(512874002)(74876001)(512934002)(31966008)(80976001)(76482001)(56776001)(81686001)(62966002)(47446002)(77982001)(54316002)(84326002)(19580405001)(79102001)(19580395003)(69226001)(74662001)(50986001)(567704001)(74482001)(47736001)(59766001)(81816001)(50226001)(49866001)(47976001)(87936001)(74502001);DIR:OUT;SFP:;SCL:1;SRVR:AMXPR04MB247;H:DB3PRD0411HT001.eurprd04.prod.outlook.com;CLIP:109.145.84.154;FPR:;RD:InfoNoRecords;A:1;MX:1;LANG:en;
>   X-OriginatorOrg: franklynnevard.co.uk
>
> Reporting-MTA: dns;AMXPR04MB247.eurprd04.prod.outlook.com
>   Received-From-MTA: dns;DB3PRD0411HT001.eurprd04.prod.outlook.com
>   Arrival-Date: Fri, 15 Nov 2013 08:54:25 +0000
>
> Final-Recipient: rfc822;pat@moonspace.co.uk Action: failed Status:
>   5.0.0 Diagnostic-Code: smtp;550 Authentication is required for relay Remote-MTA: dns;babcom-h2.lnc.net X-Display-Name: Pat Dobson

The question is, is this something that I can do something about (i.e. is it a configuration error on my users email settings) or do I need to go to the server hosts about it ? 
I have already contacted the server hosts and they say that it's nothing to do with them. What makes me suspicious is that *most* users have no problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at your log report you can see that it is returning a 550 error related to Authentication issues. This is most likely due to the fact you have not checked `My outgoing server (SMTP) requires authentication`.

[More information here:](http://portal.smartertools.com/kb/a2628/550-authentication-is-required-for-relay-when-sending-email)

> When attempting to send email using Microsoft Outlook, Outlook
>   Express, or other email client software, you may receive the message
>   "550 Authentication is required for relay" from your mail server.
>
> The reason for this error is that your email server is configured to
>   require SMTP authentication to send outgoing mail, which is a way an
>   email sender can be authorized. In order to resolve this issue you
>   will need to configure your email client (Outlook, Outlook Express,
>   Eudora, Thunderbird, etc) to send the appropriate credentials.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have notified a client who's having issues, let's hope that he can get it sorted . . .

Comment: Well he hasn't come back to me to say it's still not working so this must have solved it . . .